# Tf error after upgrading hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

after upgrading hydro I'm having the following problem:

the tf-node shows misbehavoiur even with the default launch-files i.e. I'm running the gazebo-launch files for turtlebot-navigation

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/path/to_my_map.yaml
```

Brings up the following Warning

```
[ WARN] [1390486537.516455089, 723.580000000]: Waiting on transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error:
```

A rostopic list shows

```
/amcl/parameter_descriptions
/amcl/parameter_updates
/amcl_pose
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/depth/points
/camera/parameter_descriptions
/camera/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_raw
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/clock
/cmd_vel_mux/active
/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller
/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_descriptions
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_updates
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/initialpose
/joint_states
/kobuki_safety_controller/disable
/kobuki_safety_controller/enable
/kobuki_safety_controller/reset
/map
/map_metadata
/mobile_base/commands/motor_power
/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry
/mobile_base/commands/velocity
/mobile_base/events/bumper
/mobile_base/events/cliff
/mobile_base/events/wheel_drop
/mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud
/mobile_base/sensors/core
/mobile_base/sensors/imu_data
/mobile_base_nodelet_manager/bond
/move_base/current_goal
/move_base/goal
/move_base_simple/goal
/navigation_velocity_smoother/parameter_descriptions
/navigation_velocity_smoother/parameter_updates
/navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel
/odom
/particlecloud
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/tf
/tf_static
```

In rvis the map is shown. Maybe stupid question the map is published under the topic "/map" ... and tf seems to look after "map". Did somebody experience the same problems during the last days after the upgrade?

Edit: Shouldn't be there a base_footprint topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/121391/tf-error-after-upgrading-hydro/) by [carsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/11056/carsten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-23**:
This seems to be that amcl is not running. What outputs do you get. tf doesn't show up as individual topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello dornhege,
after your reply I started my computer again and it worked. But after shutting down the move-base node and starting it again (doing so a few times) the problem occured again. But it is not easy reproducible. My first impression is that there could something wrong in the gazebo plugin which produces this output

```
Dbg Plugin model name: mobile_base
[ INFO] [1390494712.717836162, 0.010000000]: Will publish tf. [mobile_base]
[ INFO] [1390494712.722853967, 0.010000000]: GazeboRosKobuki plugin ready to go!   [mobile_base]
```

I have to restart the gazebo simulation and in most cases navigation launches successfully.

I will try to track this problem in future. But up to this point it is annoying because it worked without any problems before the upgrade.

---

Originally posted by [carsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/11056/carsten/) with karma: 16 on 2014-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-24**:
Try `rosrun tf view_frames` to see what is published by tf. If it's something due to gazebo it might be odometry missing.